# What are these symbols on the batch entry screen?

Tags: civicontribute

I am updating the contributions chapter of the user guide so I am examining in detail funcionality that I don't necessarily use every day.

To the left of the contact field in the batch entry there are some symbols. Should they be there and if so what are they for?  They are not really obvious unless you magnify the image, but there was enough there when unmagnified for me to investigate further.

[image]

Comment: on http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/ running CiviCRM 4.7.5 I tried creating a batch for Batch Data Entry and when entering rows I saw only the checkmark symbol beside the Contact field. Guessing from icons, starting with the checkmark, I think they mean select, go to end / last field, don't know but maybe play, and stop. If I had to guess what's going on, it looks like some sort of a macro recording and playback functionality. You might want to ping Coleman on this one.

Comment: One factor may be that 4.7 generally uses Font Awesome for its icons, while 4.6 and earlier use jQuery UI icons.  jQuery UI's icons are sprites, so a CSS clash could make it display a certain height (and therefore show a bunch of icons).  The new icons are font glyphs, so there aren't dozens of icons hiding around the edges, waiting to show up if you accidentally increase the dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not supposed to be there. I suspect there is something amiss with the css on your site; possibly an interfering theme. This is what the screen looks like on [dmaster.demo.civicrm.org](http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org):

[image]

On the other hand, I don't think they are working properly. I believe the checkboxes are supposed to represent that the row has been entered with valid data... but they appear regardless of what's entered. That sounds like a js bug in core.